# click anywhere on the row to check the checkbox and highlight it?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I've a script that will get the results from mysql DB and displays checkboxes with all the results in neat table format.
I want to make it like, click anywhere on the row to trigger the checkbox and highlight that entire row. with multiple rows selectable at a time.

I've already tried JS approach for onlclick and getElementById fucntion and in CSS using :checked.
So far no progress.

```
<table id="tab-1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Select</th>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">A</th>
            <th scope="col">B</th>
            <th scope="col">C</th>
            <th scope="col">D</th>
            <th scope="col">E</th>
            <th scope="col">E</th>
            <th scope="col">F</th>
            <th scope="col">G</th>
            <th scope="col">H</th>
            <th scope="col">I</th>
            <th scope="col">J</th>
            <th scope="col">k</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>"  /></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['A']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['B']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['D']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['E']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['F']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['G']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['H']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['I']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['J']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['K']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['L']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['M']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use jquery, you can try

```
$(document).on('click','tr',function(){
 $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',true);
 $(this).css('background','yellow'); // or anything else for highlighting purpose
});
```

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/UD6Tk/6/) as per comments

Comment: @syedfurqhan it's jQuery 1.6+ syntax, if you're using older version of jQuery try `attr('checked',true)` instead of `prop()`

Comment: @syedfurqhan it's working as far as i can see.. http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/UD6Tk/1/

Comment: @Joy Thanks its working, But the problem is unable to toggle. in other words the row can be checked only once. i cannot uncheck by clicking the same row.

Comment: just put the css for highlighting purpose in a class and use `toggleClass()` inside the click handler.. check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/UD6Tk/2/)

Comment: @ one more suggestion, you probably don't want the header row to be selected, so i modified the selector [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/UD6Tk/3/)

Comment: Note that you will not be able to uncheck selection if you click on checkbox.

Comment: @dfsq thanks for pointing out, [fixed here](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/UD6Tk/5/)

Comment: @TilwinJoy Behavior is not correct anyway. Clicking checkbox should check/uncheck selection, the same as clicking the row.

Comment: @dfsq didn't notice it, [fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/UD6Tk/6/) especially since OP said it was working i left the question..

Comment: @joy now its working. how do i move the selected rows from one table to another without page refresh. ? the current selection has to be removed from current table. I can do the query like select * from tab-1 where id=$selected. and also can move it to another table with insert into tab_name and so on. but dont know how to do it without refresh? may be with jquery any pointers or help?

Comment: If you just want to copy the selected rows from one table to another in same page, its  easy, look into [jQuery clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method. you can clone the `<tr>`, remove it and [append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) the clone to the other table, comments are growing way to far... If you want more accurate ans can you consider posting another question with more details such as HTML structure for the 2 tables?

Answer (score 2):

For example like this using jQuery:

```
$('#table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    $(this).find('td:first :checkbox').trigger('click');
})
.on('click', ':checkbox', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3E4Lk/2/

Comment: Its Working fine in jsfiddle, But not on my localhost, I've downloaded jquery 2.0.2 aswell. :O

Answer (score 1):

You can use the classList.toggle to toggle an active class on the row, and use `!ele.checked` to toggle the check of the checkbox.

CSS

```
tr.active {
   background:rgba(0,255,0,0.35);
}
```

Javascript

```
function rowClicked(){
   var inputs = this.getElementsByTagName("input");
   var checkboxes = [].filter.call(inputs,function(input){
      return input.type == "checkbox" && input.name == "checkbox[]";
   });
   this.classList.toggle("active");       
   if(checkboxes[0]) checkboxes[0].checked = this.classList.contains("active")

}
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
   var table = document.getElementById("tab-1");
   var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");
   for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
      rows[i].addEventListener("click",rowClicked);
   }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6d7b/1/)

Comment: Try to check the row clicking on checkbox itself.

Comment: Works fine, But when you click a checkbox you cannot select or deselect.

Comment: @syedfurqhan, i just edited it now, added `this.classList.contains("active")`, works now

Comment: But if you are going to use jQuery, might as well go with dsfq's answer as it is quite shorter.